# Async Parallel: How do I parse results

Tags: node.js, async.js

I try to calculate the total sales price in this case and it doesn't work. Am I using async.parallel correctly? How can I parse the result of calculation (totalSalesResult) to totalSales?

```
async.parallel({
 totalSales: function(totalSales) {
        Sales.find({merchant: req.user.id}).exec(function(err, results) {
            var totalShippingFees = 0;
            var totalItemSales = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                totalShippingFees += parseFloat(results[i].shippingFees);

                var items = results[i].items;
                for(var j = 0; j < items.length; i++) {
                    totalItemSales = parseFloat(items[j].sellingPrice);
                }

            }
            var totalSalesResult = parseFloat(totalShippingFees + totalItemSales);
            totalSales(null, totalSalesResult)
        });
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results.totalSales)
});
```

Comment: You don't need `async.parallel` at all, since there's only one async "task" to be performed (`Sales.find()`).

Comment: I have some other queries which I will need parallel to do it.

Comment: So what exactly isn't working? Also, make sure to check `err`

Comment: It won't stop loading ... something is blocking but I don't know what

Comment: What does _"it won't stop loading"_ mean? Loading what?

Comment: I got so many errors in this code. It's now working.

ie. this should be j++ instead of i++
`for(var j = 0; j < items.length; i++) {
                    totalItemSales = parseFloat(items[j].sellingPrice);
                }`

my fault. Sorry